# Today extension UIAlertController feature not available

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8-today-widget

I am making a today extension and I am trying to let it display an AlertController like so:

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"AlertView" message:@"I am an AlertView" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                      handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                          [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                                      }];
[alert addAction:defaultAction];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Sadly, it crashes on the first line with this error:

```
2016-02-18 11:53:46.311 App Scenes[17870:669107] *** Assertion failure in void _UIApplicationAssertForExtensionType(NSArray *__strong)(), /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3512.30.14/UIApplication.m:2446
2016-02-18 11:53:51.230 App Scenes[17870:669107] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Feature not available in extensions of type com.apple.widget-extension'
```

I am calling this code from the TodayViewController.
Can anyone tell me why this code isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you everything you need to know.

```
reason: 'Feature not available in extensions of type com.apple.widget-extension'
```

Apple obviously don't allow people to present alerts from today extensions, even if they did I can't imagine it being and enjoyable user experience.

Comment: I do realize that, but I see conflicting posts of other people that say it is possible. It is impossible then?

Comment: Looks to be yes, maybe you should ask another question with your actual problem.. why are you trying to show an alert from the today extension? - there may be a better solution.

Comment: Well, it is supposed to be an alert like: Are you sure you want to remove this  item from the widget? But I guess I will have to figure out another way then. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

iOS extension doesn't support UIAlertViewController or that matter any way to show an alert.

If you intended to show similar to alert or popup, create a custom view with UI/UX similar to alert and show/hide where ever required.